# Applying default styles in android

Tags: android, coding-style, themes

I would like to implement a settings activity which will look the same as Sound settings in android devices. First thing I'd like to know is it one big list view with many custom extended list items?

My problem is I don't know how to implement styles in xml that are on General (which is a TextView I guess) and Sound profile Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android settings I believe are all done with PreferenceActivity. [Here is the documentation for it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) and [here is a nice tutorial about how to implement one.](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences)